# How to detect insufficient funds on Paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to setup a Paypal Express Checkout payment in a PHP website. I've setup the payment flow as stated in [**Paypal documentation**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/). Additionally, I've setup a IPN callback to catch transactions on vendor account.

Now I'm wondering how to detect when buyer has insufficient funds to complete payment. Should I check `PAYMENTINFO_n_PAYMENTSTATUS` for any pending reason? Is IPN callback invoked with some particular status in this case?

Comment: I have also faced this problem. User was shown insufficient funds account error but IPN callback received everything is fine.

Comment: @UsamaAhmed: so, if I understand correctly, there's no way for discriminating insufficient funds errors in IPN callback?

Comment: Until now yes i haven't been able to find out any solution yet.